# Data transfer between components React-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, dataflow

I have two components I want to pass some property data from on page to other page/component. But unable to do that with props.

```jsx
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this.navigateTo('component2'); setState(url: 'www.xyz.com', data: 'abc' }>
  <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', height: 60, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', paddingLeft: 10 }}>
    <Image source={deals} />
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Text style={{ color: '#000' }}> Deal Center </Text>
    </View>
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

and want to read the state from component2. Can anyone please help

Comment: Do you use Flux/Redux/RxJS?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38203791/communicate-between-components-in-react-native-child-parent

Comment: lass Deals extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    popRoute: React.PropTypes.func,
    navigation: React.PropTypes.shape({
      key: React.PropTypes.string,
    }),
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      name: 'Deals',
    };
  }
 navigateTo(route) {
    this.props.navigateTo(route, 'home');
  }

Comment: Maxim Shoustin : I am using Redux

Answer (score 0):

you can write a function which navigator to 1 Component and passProps.

Example :

```
navigateTo(component){
  this.props.navigator.push({
    name: component,
    passProps: {
      url: 'www.xyz.com',
      data: 'abc' 
    }
  })
}
```

And place this function in your code like :

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.navigateTo.bind(this,'component')}>
        ...
</TouchableOpacity>
```

In your 2nd component, you can call props like :

`this.props.url` or `this.props.data`

Here is a good tutorial for React Native Navigator, [take a look](https://medium.com/react-native-training/react-native-navigator-navigating-like-a-pro-in-react-native-3cb1b6dc1e30#.wu6u1imps)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to set routes like.

```js
<Second navigator={navigator} {...route.passProps}  />
```

then only you can pass the props to the second component

then call your method on click

```js
_navigate(component,data) {
   this.props.navigator.push({
   name: component,
   passProps: {
     data:data
    }
   })
 }
```

in second component you can access data using `this.props.data`

Comment: `<Second navigator={navigator} {...route.passProps}  />` helps me. i forget to add route. Thanks.